# HTML5 Canvas Drawing a Line Whose Direction and Dimensions Change

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Firstly, I'm not a pro at HTML5. I started doing some things with HTML5 a few days ago.

Secondly, sorry for my English, I'm not very good at it and can make some mistakes.

Here's my problem...

I can draw a line with two mouse clicks, the line starts from the first click point and ends at the second click point.

But I want to create a line which starts from the first click point, changes it's direction and dimensions according to the position of mouse, then ends at the second click point. (Like the graphical password system in Android.)

Is this possible?

I found some code which can draw a line with two mouse clicks only for once, I changed it a bit and add some code myself. Here's my final code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
            #myCanvas {
            border: 1px solid #9C9898;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){

            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var point1 = new Array();
            point1['x'] = false;
            point1['y'] = false;
            var point2 = new Array();
            point2['x'] = false;
            point2['y'] = false;

            $(document).click(function(event){

                if ( false === point1['x'] || false === point1['y']) {

                    var posX1 = event.pageX;
                    var posY1 = event.pageY;

                    point1['x'] = posX1;
                    point1['y'] = posY1;

                }

                else if ( false === point2['x'] || false === point2['y'] ) {

                    var posX2 = event.pageX;            
                    var posY2 = event.pageY;

                    point2['x'] = posX2;
                    point2['y'] = posY2;
                    console.log("second");

                    context.moveTo(point1['x'], point1['y']);
                    context.lineTo(point2['x'], point2['y']);
                    context.stroke();

                    point1['x'] = point2['x'];
                    point1['y'] = point2['y'];  
                    point2['x'] = false;
                    point2['y'] = false;

                }

            });

        });

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: How will the line know to change direction? Do you mean curve towards the 2nd point?

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, just read your android lock screen description. Anyway you could post a video or screenshot of that example in action? There's a lot of custom android lock screens so Im not sure which you are referring to.

Comment: I couldn't find a video about it, sorry. I tried to explain this: http://zapp5.staticworld.net/howto/graphics/184659-android29_180.jpg
User starts from a point, then moves his/her hand to a different point, a line appears between these two points. When user moves his/her hand to a different point, start point remains the same and the direction of line changes.

Answer (score 0):

You would need some sort of animation loop to draw the line from your first click to the mouse co-ordinates as you move the mouse (every few milliseconds clear the canvas and update the line on the canvas with the new position of the mouse), then once the second click occurs stop the animation loop after the final draw, leaving the line on the canvas.

It may also be worth positioning two canvases on top of each other (one for drawing the animated line 'to-be' and one to actually store the image). This way when you finish drawing the first line and start the second the subsequent clearing will not affect the stored line on the canvas underneath.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Gary

Comment: I'll try these methods. I hope one of them will work.

Thanks Gary.